# TensorFlow: how to dot product a vector and a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, tensor, dot-product

I have a vector (which means a one-dimensional tensor) in TF of a `shape=(n,)`:

```
my_vector = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n])
```

And I have a tensor of a `shape=(m, n)`:

```
my_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[m, n])
```

I want to dot product each row of `my_tensor` by `my_vector` and obtain a `shape=(m,)` vector out of dot products. How can I do this?

I visualized it's elements to be more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tf.tensordot(my_tensor, my_vector, 1)
```